# "Cannot read property 'node' of undefined" - Gatsby/GraphQL/Prismic

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, graphql-js, prismic.io

I'm using the "gatsby-source-prismic-graphql" plugin from Gatsby to connect my Prismic repo with a component and display the blog post data as a card. The query works fine in GraphiQL, but when I implement the GraphQL query into the component Gatsby does not recognize "Prismic" in my query.

Ive tried displaying other data such as site metadata and that is working with no problems

Here is the Git repo: https://github.com/ENEIV/PrometheusIgnis

gatsby-config.js

```
// Prismic CMS
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-prismic-graphql`,
      options: {
        repositoryName: `prometheus`,
        accessToken: process.env.PRISMIC_KEY,
    },
```

Component querying data from Prismic

```
import React from "react"
import { RichText } from "prismic-reactjs"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

const articlesQuery = graphql`
  query {
    prismic {
      allArticless(uid: "prometheus-prismic-testing-1") {
        edges {
          node {
            article_title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

const Posts = () => (
  // const doc = data.prismic.allArticless.edges.slice(0, 1).pop()
  // if (!doc) return null
  <StaticQuery
    query={articlesQuery}
    render={data => (
      <h1>{RichText.render(data.prismic.edges.node.article_title)}</h1>
    )}
  />
)

export default Posts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you missing the 'allArticless' (allArticles, no ?) object in you RichText render `{RichText.render(data.prismic.allArticles.edges.node.article_title)}`.

By the way, I think you've got an array of multiple result in edges, no ? With allArticless you've got multiple page, so if the solution above doesn't work, try to map your result

```
data => { data.prismic.edges.map((article, index) => (
   <h1 key={`articleTitle-${index}}>{RichText.render(article.article_title)}</h1>
)}
```

Comment: Wow -_-. Thanks for the help Logan. The code works but the RichText.render is throwing a warning in the browser "text argument should be an Array" and is not rendering the text, but the "article_title" is an array. _From GraphiQL_ `"node": {
              "article_title": [
                {
                  "type": "heading3",
                  "text": "Prometheus Test #3",
                  "spans": []
                }
              ]
            }`

Answer (score 0):

There is a BIG DIFFERENCE between pulling data from a CMS through GraphQL using an "All..." and pulling data using a Single name of the query detail.
And when calling multiple data, It's better to use a map method (map function) to pull all the data you need.

For example:

```
data => { data.prismic.edges.map((article, index) => (<h1 key={`articleTitle-${index}}>{RichText.render(article.article_title)}</h1>)}
```

As Logan just solved it.